# How to make a reusable code block into a view helper?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.5

I have this simple code block and it is on one of my templates but I would like to place it as a helper so it would be accessible to all of my views.

```
@hidden(field: Field) = {
    @defining(field) { formField =>
        <input type="hidden" name="@formField.name" id="@formField.id" value="@formField.value">
    }
}

@hidden(myForm("xyz"))
```

I've tried to create a separated template but it did not work, how can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The separate template must work.

Create the `hidden.scala.html` in the root of the `view` folder. The content is

```
@(formField: Field)
<input type="hidden" name="@formField.name" id="@formField.id" value="@formField.value">
```

You can call this template from another template like `@hidden(myForm("xyz"))`